# Why are columns no longer resizable in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, extjs4, upgrade, extjs6, extjs-grid

In ExtJs 4 all columns in a `Ext.grid.Panel` were automatically resizable. After upgrading to ExtJs 6.2, it is no longer possible to resize te column. The cursor will still change to `resize`, but resizing no longer works.

I looked into the [documentation of Column.resizable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-resizable), and it seams that `resizable: true` is still the default.

Why then is it, that resizing no longer works?

Edit: I observe the same behavior with the splitters of border layout: the cursor changes to `resize`, but I'm not able to drag the splitter.

Comment: This looks more like a some kind of bug, where do you see this behavior? Do you have some steps to reproduce? The columns are resizable by default http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#array-grid

Comment: @pagep Thanks. Yes it looks like a bug. I just created a fiddle where it works. Difficult to find where the problem comes from. I dont have any error messages.

Comment: Maybe you can try to get that grid columns by Ext Component query http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html  and check their attribute resizable.

Comment: They are all `resizable: true`

Comment: I stripped down my app to only keep 8 files out of 300, and the bug went away. Now I have to add the others back and find the offending code in a binary search :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I reaffected `document.id = ...`

There is not much chance someone else will have the same problem, but still, this is the answer.

Comment: Hey, 
thats rather old - maybe someone is still listening: I have a similar issue - What do you mean by "reaffected"? Cheers

Comment: @oberbics Somewhere in third party code was a statement `document.id = ... `. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

in your grid class specify:

```
requires: [
    'Ext.grid.plugin.ColumnResizing'
],

plugins: 'columnresizing',
```

Comment: This only applies to the modern toolkit. If upgrading from 4.x then OP will be using classic toolkit.